# Opening an activity from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a bottom navigation bar that switches between 5 fragments. One of these 5 buttons should open WebView (newsfeed) and display some HTML. The code that calls the newsfeed.xml is this:

```
public class newsfeedFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed,container,false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Now I followed a youtube tutorial to pull the HTML from a website (code below). In the tutorial, the code is in it's own activity and not called within a fragment. I am not sure how to combine these 2 code snippets to create the webview inside my fragment. Help would be much appreciated!

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: The title and question text are somewhat inconsistent. Do you want to start an activity from a fragment or open a web view inside a fragment?

Comment: Actually, ideal would be to have the webview (second code snippet) inside the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to load the webview into the fragment?

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed,container,false)

WebView webview = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.loadUrl("http://www.website.com")
    return v;
}
```

So inflate the Layout and afterwards call findviewbyid with your new layout and then you could do anything you want with your webview and it is loaded in your Fragment. Hopefully the solution for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code anywhere in the fragment to open the activity:-

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),ActivitytoOpen.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take `WebView` in your newsfeed layout, and do the same thing in fragment.